# gradle project + cobertura - why can't I generate reports for multiple subprojects?

Tags: gradle, report, cobertura

On the root level project, I have a `build.gradle` with the following:

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.2.1"
    id 'net.saliman.cobertura' version '2.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'cobertura'

cobertura {
    coverageFormats = ['html', 'xml']
    coverageReportDir = new File("$projectDir/reports/cobertura")
    rootProject.subprojects.each {
        coverageReportDir = new File("$it.name/reports/cobertura")
    }
}
```

But when I run `./gradlew cobertura` it will only generate the reports/cobertura directory on the root project.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
configure(allprojects) {

plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.2.1"
    id 'net.saliman.cobertura' version '2.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'cobertura'

cobertura {
    coverageFormats = ['html', 'xml']
    coverageReportDir = new File("$projectDir/reports/cobertura")
    rootProject.subprojects.each {
        coverageReportDir = new File("$it.name/reports/cobertura")
    }
}
}
```